# Ubuntu One Storage Options

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am looking at Purchasing a Ubuntu One Storage Account, and all I can find is a 20Gb Storage Option. I will Primarily use this Cloud Service for Storing my Family Photo Albums, and will need approx. 47Gb to store my Current Library, not Including more space for more Pictures as it is Continually Growing. Is there a way to Purchase more then 20Gb? And if so, how do I go about doing this?

Thanks so much!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The storage is sold in units of 20GB. So you can just buy more 20GB units. To do so sign in and go to this URL:

- https://one.ubuntu.com/services/add-storage/

And then click on the arrows to add as much space as you need.